# Database connection in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, connection

I have a class name db_access that is extended to db_connection which is running the query; my class db_access has a method named result, you can see I just echo the property name query inside my classes, and it runs ok. Now my problem is in the db_connection, how can I run my host connection automatically inside the constructor? I done function named connect() and call that inside the run() ,but i want it to be automatically run, (by the way that db_access is extended from some class also)
Please help.

```
class db_access extends db_connection
{       
    public function result()
    {           
                echo $this->query;
            $this->run();           

    }       
}


class db_connection{    
      private $link;      

      public function __construct() {    
        $this->link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());         
        mysql_select_db('jsample');
      }

    public function run(){
        echo $this->query;
        mysql_query($this->query) or die(mysql_error());    
    }       
}
```

Comment: i mean the mysql_query() inside the run() will work, because now it trow error say, no database selected

Comment: How are you calling your `db_access`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend connecting to a database in the constructor. It severely cuts down on the reusability of the class.

Comment: yes i actually call the result() and it echo my query

Comment: @Bill well, the class is called db_connection, so I would be surprised if it didn't connect to a database ;-)

Comment: @avien: You dint declare the $query anywhere. Also how you are initializing it before calling run()?

Comment: actually db_access is extended from some class also and there i put $this->query and assign the values , and the $this->query works fine, it return my query when i place it both in my db_connection and db_access, the problem is my connection

Comment: Of course it needs to connect to the database, but taking control away of when it connects makes it less useful. The next person may not want to connect until well after it is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

For one, in your `db_connection::run()` you should pass `$this->link` to `mysql_query`:

```
public function run()
{
    echo $this->query;
    mysql_query($this->query, $this->link) or die(mysql_error());    
}
```

Second, you should check whether `mysql_select_db()` returned `true` or `false`:

```
if (false === mysql_select_db('jsample', $this->link)) {
    die("Could not select database");
}
```

Third, where are you setting `$this->query`?

Lastly, you should use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. The `mysql_` family function has been deprecated and will eventually be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever set the "query" property. So I think you left out some code.
I'll bet you also left out a __construct for db_access. In PHP, you have to manually chain up your constructors. So inside db_access::_*construct you need to call parent::*_construct()

See the PHP documentation on [__construct](http://id.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct).